# UIAlertController's actionSheet gives constraint error on iOS 12.2 / 12.3

Tags: swift5, uialertcontroller, ios12

On iOS 12.2, while using `UIAlertController`'s `actionSheet`, Xcode gives constraint error. Anyone having this problem?

This same code runs on iOS 12.1 with no error.

I have tested this code on Xcode 10.2 and 10.1.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let Click : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(Click)
        Click.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        Click.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    
    @objc func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default)
    
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        
        optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001b6ee0 UIView:0x7fe3b6513020.width == - 16   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001b6ee0 UIView:0x7fe3b6513020.width == - 16   (active)>
```

PS:

Just to make sure that the problem is on `UIAlertController`, I removed everything and updated the code as below, but I received the same error:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default)
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        
        optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i've tested your code, it runs perfectly. 
can you provide an actual screen shot

Comment: @SanadBarjawi https://imgur.com/Hek2eQT here is the error. this problem occur only on iOS 12.2

Comment: what's your xCode Version?

Comment: @SanadBarjawi tested on  Xcode 10.2 and Xcode 10.1 on iOS 12.1 and 12.2 problem shows up on iOS 12.2 only

Comment: try to give the Click button a fixed width

Comment: @SanadBarjawi I did. button is not the problem.

Comment: does it occur if you commented the actionSheet code?

Comment: @SanadBarjawi without actionSheet no error

Comment: i think that this issue comes from the parent View, so try to added another parent view with zeroes as leading trailing top and bottom, then add your current elements to it (this is just for testing)

Comment: @SanadBarjawi I add tempView with zeroes as leading trailing top and bottom. then added a button in that view. but same problem I don't think button is the problem . Something is wrong with UIAlertController in iOS 12.2. just to make sure its not the button I completely remove another code and just put the UIAlertController code in ViewDidAppear. same problem

Comment: in viewDidLoad, try to view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @SanadBarjawi nope not working.

Comment: suppose that its the 12.2 update issue then

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem in Xcode 10.2 running iOS 12.2--guessing it's a bug! I'm planning to just ignore it.

Comment: Same issue with 12.2. 12.1 doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue with iOS 12.2

Comment: Duplicate of [Swift default AlertViewController breaking constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653187/swift-default-alertviewcontroller-breaking-constraints), we may as well consolidate these. And please file a bug report.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue: iOS 12.2 with iPhone action sheet , I am using objective-C code and the same code has been working for years, it logs this error only for  iOS 12.2

Comment: @matt I inform apple about the problem. waiting for respond, and [Swift default AlertViewController breaking constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653187/swift-default-alertviewcontroller-breaking-constraints) is the Duplicate one. this problem was raise way before the one you mention in the link. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Even with 12.3 as well, XCode 10.2.1

Comment: Same issue here. iOS 12.3.1

Comment: The workaround is to find the constraint with constant < 0 and decrease its priority.

if let constraints = alertViewController.view?.subviews.first?.constraints {
  for constraint in constraints {
    if constraint.constant < 0 {
      constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: constraint.priority.rawValue - 1)
    }
  }
}

Comment: Another way is to negate the constant to make it positive:

if let constraints = alertViewController.view?.subviews.first?.constraints {
  for constraint in constraints {
    if constraint.constant < 0 {
      constraint.constant = -constraint.constant
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 165):

It's a bug in iOS versions:

- 12.2
- 12.3
- 12.4
- 13.0
- 13.1
- 13.2
- 13.2.3
- 13.3
- 13.4
- 13.4.1
- 13.5
- 13.5.1
- 13.6
- 14.0
- 14.1
- 14.2
- 14.4

The only thing we can do is to file a bug report to Apple (I just did that and you should too).

I'll try to update answer for a new versions of iOS if the bug still will be present. Help appreciated.

Comment: The bug continues in iOS 13 beta 2.

Comment: continues in beta 7

Comment: continues in iOS 13 official version

Comment: iOS 13.2 checking in, issue remains

Comment: continues in iOS 13.2.3

Comment: It's also present in ios 13.3

Comment: i laugh every time i see this update

Comment: iOS 13.4 and counting...

Comment: iOS 13.4.1 as well

Comment: I noticed this bug again today on iOS 13.4.1. Funny thing that I talked to one of Apple's engineers during last years WWDC and they said they know about it and it should be fixed in iOS 13.0. Well, maybe iOS 14.0.

Comment: iOS 13.5 also has this issue

Comment: still present in iOS 13.5

Comment: This is actually hilarious

Comment: 22 June 2020, still seeing this error. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Still here on iOS 14 beta 2

Comment: still present in 13.6

Comment: still here on iOS 14

Comment: Continues at iOS 14

Comment: Seeing it constantly in iOS 14

Comment: Still present in iOS 14.4.

Comment: This really is hilarious. WTF, Apple?!  Bug report filed.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in iOS 14.5 - tested in a Swift 5/Xcode 12.5/iOS 12.3 project with the iPhone SE2 simulator. In the same project the iPhone SE 12.4 simulator logs the message in console.